# Visual Studio 2013 command line build without specific dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, command-line

Good Day.
I have two machines. First is clean build machine without any 3party software installed. Visual Studio 2013 installed on it for build purposes. Build tasks executed using command line.

The second is client machine which has 3party software installed but doesn't have VS. Client machine uses apps builded on first machine.

I have project with reference to 3party library (somelib.dll for example) which I need to build on first machine using command line. somelib.dll exists only on client machine where the built app intended to run.

Currently I have an exception "reference not found" while trying to build project using devenv.exe command line.

The question is which parameter for build I should use to ignore lack of somelib.dll reference on first machine. Or if it even possible?

Comment: the c# compilers are smart enough to know if a reference is required or not. you have to include it to build it.

Comment: No, you have to include the libraries, otherwise how is the compiler supposed to tell if the code calling it is correct or not?